# Create SSRS Data Driven Subscription using PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, reporting-services

**Edit: Added the whole converted c# to PowerShell with issue**

I'm trying to convert MSDN C# code to PowerShell script.
Here's the MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createdatadrivensubscription.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3)

I almost finished the conversion but I encounter some issues for my last line.

This is the complete error message: Exception calling "CreateDataDrivenSubscription" with "7" argument(s): "There was an error generating the XML document."

Below is the code snippet for the 7th argument in creating data driven subscription.

Here's the PowerShell script:

```
$Parameters | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name $EMPID.ParameterName -Value $EMPID.FieldAlias

$ReportYear = New-Object $ParameterValue
$ReportYear.Name = "ReportYear"
$ReportYear.Value = "2017"

$Parameters | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name $ReportYear.Name -Value $ReportYear.Value

$ReportMonth = New-Object $ParameterValue

$ReportMonth.Name = "ReportMonth"
$ReportMonth.Value = "6"

$Parameters | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $ReportMonth.Name -Value $ReportMonth.Value


$SubscriptionID = $objWebServerProxy.CreateDataDrivenSubscription($Report,$Settings,$arrDataRetrievalPlan,$Description,$EventType,$MatchData,$Parameters)
```

Here's the C# code

```
ParameterValueOrFieldReference[] parameters = new ParameterValueOrFieldReference[3];

ParameterFieldReference empID = new ParameterFieldReference(); // Data-driven.
empID.ParameterName = "EmpID";
empID.FieldAlias = "EmpID";
parameters[0] = empID;

ParameterValue reportYear = new ParameterValue();
reportYear.Name = "ReportYear";
reportYear.Value = "2004";
parameters[1] = reportYear;

ParameterValue reportMonth = new ParameterValue();
reportMonth.Name = "ReportMonth";
reportMonth.Value = "6"; // June
parameters[2] = reportMonth;

try
{
    string subscriptionID = rs.CreateDataDrivenSubscription( 
report, settings, dataRetrieval, description, eventType, matchData, parameters);
```

Can you tell me where did I miss on the conversion?

Here's my whole converted script.

```
$URI = "URI"

$objWebServerProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URI -UseDefaultCredential -ErrorAction Stop

$Namespace = $objWebServerProxy.GetType().Namespace
$ExtensionSettigs = ($Namespace + '.ExtensionSettings')
$ParameterValueOrFieldReference = ($Namespace + '.ParameterValueOrFieldReference')
$ParameterFieldReference = ($Namespace + '.ParameterFieldReference')
$ParameterValue = ($Namespace + '.ParameterValue')
$Datasource = ($Namespace + '.DataSource')
$DataSourceDefinition = ($Namespace + '.DataSourceDefinition')
$Field = ($Namespace + '.Field')
$CredentialRetrievalEnum = ($Namespace + '.CredentialRetrievalEnum')
$DataSetDefinition = ($Namespace + '.DataSetDefinition')
$QueryDefinition = ($Namespace + '.QueryDefinition')
$DataSetDefinition = ($Namespace +'.DataSetDefinition')
$DataRetrievalPlan = ($Namespace+'.DataRetrievalPlan')
$ScheduleReference = ($Namespace+'.ScheduleReference')

$NameSharedSchedule="Mike_Test";
$NeverExpireSchedule= $objWebServerProxy.ListSchedules([System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value) | where {$_.Name -eq "$NameSharedSchedule"}
$NeverExpireScheduleID = $NeverExpireSchedule.scheduleid;
$NeverExpireDescription = $NeverExpireSchedule.Description;
$NeverExpireDefinition = $NeverExpireSchedule.Definition;
#Write-Host "Found Shared Schedule: '$NameSharedSchedule' with id $NeverExpireScheduleID and definition $NeverExpireDescription";

$NeverExpireScheduleRef =New-Object $ScheduleReference
$NeverExpireScheduleRef.ScheduleID=$NeverExpireScheduleID;

#$Report = "/ForMigration/Subscription_Test/SSRSRationalization_ExecutionLog_LastEightDays"
$Report = "/Gayatree/GTest/ExecutionLog_LastEightDays"
$Description = "My new Data Driven Subscription"

$Settings = New-Object $ExtensionSettigs

$Settings.Extension = "Report Server Email";

$ExtensionParams = New-Object $ParameterValueOrFieldReference

#$ExtensionParams.ParameterValueOrFieldReference ='8'



$To = New-Object $ParameterFieldReference 
$To.ParameterName = "TO"
$To.FieldAlias = "Email"

$ExtensionParams | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name $To.ParameterName -Value $To.FieldAlias

$ReplyTo = New-Object $ParameterValue
$ReplyTo.Name = "ReplyTo"
$ReplyTo.Value = "Email"

$ExtensionParams | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name $ReplyTo.Name -Value $ReplyTo.Value

$IncludeReport = New-Object $ParameterValue
$IncludeReport.Name = "IncludeReport"
$IncludeReport.Value = $false

$ExtensionParams | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name $IncludeReport.Name -Value $IncludeReport.Value

$RenderFormat = new-object $ParameterValue
$RenderFormat.Name = "ReportFormat";
$RenderFormat.Value = "HTML4.0"

$ExtensionParams | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name $RenderFormat.Name -Value $RenderFormat.Value

$Priority = New-Object $ParameterValue
$Priority.Name = "Priority"
$Priority.Value = "Normal"

$ExtensionParams | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name $Priority.Name -Value $Priority.Value

$Subject = New-Object $ParameterValue
$Subject.Name = "Subject"
$Subject.Value = "Your sales report"
$ExtensionParams | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name $Subject.Name -Value $Subject.Value

$Comment = New-Object $ParameterValue
$Comment.Name = "Comment"
$Comment.Value = "Here is the link to your report."

$ExtensionParams | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name $Comment.Name -Value $Comment.Value 

$IncludeLink = New-Object $ParameterValue
$IncludeLink.Name = "IncludeLink";
$IncludeLink.Value = $true

$ExtensionParams | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -name $IncludeLink.Name -Value $IncludeLink.Value

$Settings.ParameterValues = $ExtensionParams



$DSName = New-Object $Datasource
$DSName.Name = "Mike_Test"

<#
$DSDefinition = New-Object $DataSourceDefinition
$CredentialRetrieval = New-Object $CredentialRetrievalEnum
$CredentialRetrieval.value__ = 1

$DSDefinition.ConnectString = "Data source = server;Initial Catalog = ReportServer"
$DSDefinition.CredentialRetrieval = $CredentialRetrieval
$DSDefinition.Enabled = $true
$DSDefinition.EnabledSpecified = $true
$DSDefinition.Extension = "SQL"
$DSDefinition.ImpersonateUserSpecified = $false
$DSDefinition.UserName = "Username"
$DSDefinition.Password = "Password"

#>
$DS = $objWebServerProxy.ListChildren('/',$false)|Where-Object {$_.TypeName -eq "DataSource"}

   foreach($DSS in $DS){
   $anotherPass = $DSS.path
$another = $objWebServerProxy.GetDataSourceContents("$anotherPass")
$another.Password = "TestPass"
}
$another
$DSName.Item = $another

$FieldList = New-Object $Field
$FieldList.Name = "EmailAddress"
$FieldList.Alias = "EmailAddress"

$FieldList | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -name $FieldList.Name -Value $FieldList.Alias

$FieldList.Name = "EmpID"
$FieldList.Alias = "EmpID"

$FieldList | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -name $FieldList.Name -Value $FieldList.Alias


$DataSetDef = New-Object $DataSetDefinition

$DataSetDef.AccentSensitivitySpecified = $false
$DataSetDef.CaseSensitivitySpecified = $false
$DataSetDef.KanatypeSensitivitySpecified = $false
$DataSetDef.WidthSensitivitySpecified = $false
$DataSetDef.Fields = $FieldList


$arrQueryDefinition = New-Object $QueryDefinition
$arrQueryDefinition.CommandText = "Select getdate()"
$arrQueryDefinition.CommandType = "Text"
$arrQueryDefinition.Timeout = '45'
$arrQueryDefinition.TimeoutSpecified = $true
$DataSetDef.Query = $arrQueryDefinition
$Results = New-Object $DataSetDefinition
$Bool = $true
$Name = "Parameter"
$DSDefinition

$DataSetDef


$DSName
$Results = $objWebServerProxy.PrepareQuery($DSName,$DataSetDef,[ref]$Bool,[ref]$Name)

$arrDataRetrievalPlan = New-Object $DataRetrievalPlan
$arrDataRetrievalPlan.DataSet = $Results
$arrDataRetrievalPlan.Item = $another

$EventType = "TimedSubscription";
$MatchData = $NeverExpireScheduleID

$Parameters = New-Object $ParameterValueOrFieldReference
#
$EMPID = New-Object $ParameterFieldReference
$EMPID.ParameterName = "EmpID"
$EMPID.FieldAlias = "EmpID"

$Parameters | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name $EMPID.ParameterName -Value $EMPID.FieldAlias

$ReportYear = New-Object $ParameterValue
$ReportYear.Name = "ReportYear"
$ReportYear.Value = "2017"

$Parameters | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name $ReportYear.Name -Value $ReportYear.Value

$ReportMonth = New-Object $ParameterValue

$ReportMonth.Name = "ReportMonth"
$ReportMonth.Value = "6"

$Parameters | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $ReportMonth.Name -Value $ReportMonth.Value



$SubscriptionID = $objWebServerProxy.CreateDataDrivenSubscription($Report,$Settings,$arrDataRetrievalPlan,$Description,$EventType,$MatchData,$Parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the way you're creating the ParameterValue instances works - I can't tell for sure since the $ParameterValue declaration is missing, but chances are this causes the problem. 
You might want to try something more along the lines of this:

```
$reportServerUri = "http://localhost/reportserver/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl"
$rs = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $reportServerUri -UseDefaultCredential -Namespace "SSRS"

# Note the difference, here we use the type generated when creating the webservice proxy:
$ReportYear = New-Object SSRS.ParameterValue 
$ReportYear.Name = "ReportYear"
$ReportYear.Value = "2017"
```

See my [blog post here](https://blogs.infosupport.com/managing-ssrs-reports-with-powershell/) for a quick tutorial.

**Edit**
To pinpoint which argument of `CreateDataDrivenSubscription` the error is, try substituting one or more arguments with `$null` - sure it might be invalid according to the method's documentation, but the null checks only occur once the call has been successfully sent to the server and deserialized.

In other words, if substituting the `$Parameters` argument with `$null` does not throw the "error generating XML document", then the error is in the `$Parameters` argument:

```
$SubscriptionID = $objWebServerProxy.CreateDataDrivenSubscription($Report,$Settings,
           $arrDataRetrievalPlan,$Description,$EventType,$MatchData,$null)
```

Comment: Yes. I already seen your blog and I learn basic scripting in SSRS because of it. I thank you for that one.
Actually, there'll be issues if you have written your namespace like that. I usually use the auto-generated namespace when I create a web proxy.

 $Namespace = $objWebServerProxy.GetType().Namespace
 $ParameterValue = ($Namespace + '.ParameterValue')

And then create an object using this, Anyway to avoid confusion I'll also add a comment for my whole script.

Comment: Yes. It has the same error message when I converted it to $null.

I do have a question, is my conversion for this line in C# is correct?

You may refer to my code snippet below.

Comment: <!-- Language: C#: -->

 ParameterValueOrFieldReference[] parameters = new ParameterValueOrFieldReference[3];
 ParameterFieldReference empID = new ParameterFieldReference();
 empID.ParameterName = "EmpID";
 empID.FieldAlias = "EmpID";
 parameters[0] = empID;

               PowerShell:

 $ParameterValueOrFieldReference = ($Namespace + '.ParameterValueOrFieldReference')
 $EMPID = New-Object $ParameterFieldReference
 $EMPID.ParameterName = "EmpID"
 $EMPID.FieldAlias = "EmpID"

 $Parameters | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name $EMPID.ParameterName -Value $EMPID.FieldAlias